# Get message from RawReactionActionEvent (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I get the message a reaction is used on? I know you can get the message with context, but how can I use the attributes
`channel_id` `guild_id` and `message_id`
to get the original message? This seems like enough information

I have tried using `client.http.edit_message` and `client.http.delete_message` which seems to work until using an embed. Whenever used, `TypeError: Object of type Embed is not JSON serializable` is raised

Comment: MessageReference seems to be the answer, as it creates a reference to a message based on the three ids mentioned, but I can't figure out how to get the original message object from the reference either

Comment: what about getting the channel using `bot.get_channel(channel_id)` then getting the message using `await channel.fetch_message(message_id)`

Comment: btw about the embed thing, when using raw HTTP methods pass `embed.to_dict()` instead of the embed object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

- Independent of the bot's cache, requires more API calls:

```py
async def fetch_message(payload):
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    return message
```

- Depends on bot's cache, requires less API calls:

```py
async def get_message(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await bot.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    return message
```